# Web Audio API - Get correct frequency

Tags: javascript, audio, web, frequency-analysis

I am using the Web Audio API to get the frequency of the sound, which is coming from the microphone. For this I found some useful code on this github repo: https://gist.github.com/giraj/250decbbc50ce091f79e .

Now my problem is, that I am getting a lot of different frequencies, for only one little sound. This sound might be from my voice, or from an instrument.

These frequencies are like between 90 and 4000Hz. But as I know, one note of a human voice or from an instrument, only can have one single frequency amount in Hz. And I am pretty sure, that I am only playing one single tone.

So how can I know, which frequency of the 3 or 4 frequencies per tone is the one I am searching. I need this value, to recognize musical notes like C, D, E from their frequencies. I hope this question isn't off-topic, because I really tried hard to find a solution and I don't know if this is a solveable issue from the API itself, or if I have to eliminate some frequencies somehow. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Edit: And I want to add, that I never reach the same values of the notes as listed in this frequency list: http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html . I am using a piano app, which is giving always the correct frequencies on frequency apps on the play store. So I even doubt the results I am receiving.

Comment: Sounds are almost never a single frequency -- the only kind that (rarely) are are artificial. The things that we perceive as tones are actually composed of content at one frequency `f` (which is called the fundamental, and is what you're thinking of) and a series of "harmonics," content at all the multiples of `f` (`2f, 3f, 4f, 5f, etc.`). To determine the note being played, you have to take that into account. One way to do this is to look for the distance (`f`) between the harmonics in the spectrogram.

Comment: Thanks for this advice, didn't know that before. I will think about this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've been messing with the same question and have some interesting partial answers. This website http://www.phy.mtu.edu/~suits/Physicsofmusic.html has a huge amount of information explain music in math terms and is super helpful.

I wrote something that uses a web audio analyser and simply buckets the fft results into bins by musical pitch - it gives you a graphic of what the fft results are and is kind of indicative of what frequencies are actually in the sound.  It's at https://aerik.github.io/NoteDetector.htm.

After I started with that I found another guy's code that uses "auto-correlation" to detect the fundamental.  This might be closer to what you're looking for:  https://github.com/cwilso/PitchDetect  The problem I'm having with that is it that, while it works well for fairly pure tones, it still has a lot of noise.

I'm thinking of combining his approach with mine by comparing the autocorrelation result with the signal strength from the fft.

It's a fun project, but I don't think there are any simple answers.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a professional singer, pianist, and voice teacher transitioning into code, so I think I can speak to some of the confusing results you're getting here.

Bottom line: you are actually producing many different frequencies at the same time when you sing or play a note on an instrument, so chances are the results you're seeing are accurate. What you're aiming for, however, is almost certainly the fundamental pitch, which is the lowest one.

Longer, more complex answer with physics: Unless you're looking at a sine wave (sounds like a mechanical beep, and won't come out of a decent musical instrument), the sound you're hearing probably contains many different frequencies. The sound is made up of a fundamental pitch (the lowest frequency, and usually the one we're talking about when we name a pitch in music), and a whole lot of overtones (other, higher frequencies that make up the characteristic sound of an instrument, or for singers, even a vowel).

Let's pick a number that's easy to work with: imagine your fundamental pitch is 100hz. We'll call that C1 for convenience in discussing musical implications (though it's not actually a C), and the numbers represent octave leaps with octaves ranging from C up to B. You could potentially have overtones at any of the following pitches: 200hz (C2), 300hz (G2), 400hz (C3), 500hz (E3), 600hz (G3), 700hz (Bb3), 800hz (C4), 900 hz (D4), 1000hz (E4), etc. Different instruments might make some overtones pop out more than others, or skip some of these entirely (many will skip every other overtone), but all the overtones will be within this pattern.

Notice that all the overtones are multiples of the fundamental. That means you can use the pattern in all those other pitches you see to figure out the fundamental pitch underneath. From a musical standpoint, you might also notice that the pitches you see first in this overtone series are the ones we consider most consonant — octaves, perfect 5ths, major 3rds, major triads. This is not a coincidence, and the way the overtones line up with these other pitches is almost certainly why we find them pretty to listen to.

Boiling all this down to how you'd determine the fundamental pitch given a series of overtones presumably resulting from the same fundamental: you're essentially looking for the greatest common factor of the various frequencies you'll see. It is probably also the lowest frequency you detected, but be careful with this heuristic, because you may have unrelated noise in your signal. Anything that doesn't fall into your nice list of multiples is probably noise.

All this gets much more complicated, of course, when you play more than one (fundamental) pitch at once. I'm pondering chord detection myself, and found your question while looking for what people have already done in this area and how I can build on it.